# Problema con regex en Android Studio - No extrae datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, regex

estoy intentando sacar un PID mediante expresiones regulares (regex) pero al momento de usar *find()* no es capaz de encontrarlo, la línea que analiza sigue un formato así:

```
> E/AndroidRuntime(14700): Process: com.example.log_v_02, PID: 14700
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4700): Process: com.example.log_v_02, PID: 14700
```

Sin embargo no puedo extraer los numeros en los parentesis que en este caso sería 14700 y 4700 (a veces cuando tiene un espacio después del primer parentesis, mi código es el siguiente:

```
    Pattern saca_pid = Pattern.compile("(\\\\s*(\\\\d+)):");
    StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (!((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Matcher encuentra_pid = saca_pid.matcher(line);
        if(encuentra_pid.find()){
            String pid = encuentra_pid.group(1);
            int num_pid = Integer.parseInt(pid);
        }

        }
```

Agradecería muchisímo su ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular: `[(][ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*[)]`

La podrías utilizar en tu código java de esta manera, por ejemplo:

```
String datos = "> E/AndroidRuntime(14700): Process: com.example.log_v_02, PID: 14700 " +
               "> E/AndroidRuntime( 4700): Process: com.example.log_v_02, PID: 14700 ";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[(][ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*[)]");
Matcher m = r.matcher(datos);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Se ha encontrado valor: " + m.group(1) );
}
```

Tienes una demo del código [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/1FBlRF).

Answer (score 0):

Me gusta usar esta [pagina](https://regex101.com/) para comprobar los regex. Va muy bien.

Para lo que tu pides, el regex que quieres es:
`\s*\(?(\W)\d*\)`

Y si lo escapamos para que no tengas problemas luego en java, debería de ser `\\s*\\(?(\\W)\\d*\\)`

Espero que te sea util

Comment: Gracias Cadeq, pero no funciono :( y este sería la expresión a Java del que me diste: \\s*\\(\\?(\\w)\\d*\\) Si embargo aún no funciona :(

Comment: @ZeroLuis Las doble contra barra de los paréntesis deben de permanecer para que el regex considere el paréntesis como un caracter normal, no como uno especial de regex. Del que te puse primero, debes de añadir una segunda contrabarra a todos los que tienen una. En tu caso, añadiste dos al ? y no debe de tener.

Comment: así es, los pusé pero por alguna razón al comentar aquí no los pone, pero sí los puse en mi código y no funciono :(

Comment: Vale pues entonces ya no tengo ni idea. Si vas a la pagina que te puse, pones el texto de prueba que pusiste y el regex que te puesto (sin duplicar los `\`) veras que selecciona lo que pides.